# If Chrome is already running, it will not open any local files

Tags: google-chrome

If Chrome is already running, it will not open a local file.

However, if I quit Chrome, and try to open a local file, it works.

My Chrome is up to date, Version 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit)

[GIF of issue in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7Fj2.gif)